# rails 4.2, Paperclip, has_attached_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have checked few tutorials, and thing is not working.

Env is rails 4.2 and Paperclip ~4.3.

When having one image, I use 'has_attached_file :image_1' and it works.
I need to add 1(maybe 2) images more, when trying:

has_attached_file :image_1
has_attached_file :image_2

approach and creating 2 separate form entries, second image is not saved.

Maybe i am going into not designed direction, anyway this direction seems to have sense for me.

Comment: Have you updated your strong parameters?  `params.require(:model).permit(:image_1, :image_2)`

Comment: did you added the paperclip columns for `:image_2 `?

Comment: Run `rails generate paperclip YourModel image_2` and then update your permitted parameters in YourModelController.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for hints.

Japed, yes, i 'forgot' to add ':image_2' into parameters in controller.

btw rails server log displayed  ~'unpermitted paremeter'.